# Hover in popup in Folium

Tags: python, folium

With a simple example like this:

```
import folium

map_1 = folium.Map(location=[45.372, -121.6972], zoom_start=12,
                   tiles='Stamen Terrain')
folium.Marker([45.3288, -121.6625], popup='Mt. Hood Meadows').add_to(map_1)
map_1
```

Can you make a popup appear just by putting the mouse up?
Is this possible with folium?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

It turns out that this functionality has been put into folium's codebase.

Simply add the `tooltip` argument, like so:

```
import folium

map_1 = folium.Map(location=[45.372, -121.6972], zoom_start=12, tiles='Stamen Terrain',
                   tooltip = 'This tooltip will appear on hover' # THIS
                  )
folium.Marker([45.3288, -121.6625], popup='Mt. Hood Meadows').add_to(map_1)
map_1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it easily from folium. But since folium does create LeafletJS code you can modify the output to make it work. For that you will have to add to the resulting html the code stated in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/how-to-show-a-popup-on-mouse-over-not-on-click):

```
    marker.bindPopup("Popup content");
    marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
        this.openPopup();
    });
    marker.on('mouseout', function (e) {
        this.closePopup();
    });
```

If you have many markers this might become a difficult task, but you can do it through python (though it will not look pretty). Pseudocode:

```
import re

with open("map.html") as inf:
    txt = inf.read()

#Find all the markers names given by folium
markers = re.findall(r'\bmarker_\w+', txt)

for marker in markers:
   # Add the code given before to the string txt

# Save the new map
with open("new_map.html", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(txt)
```

This codes opens the generated html file, find all the markers, and adds the code for each marker.

Answer (score 2):

In the  example below, popup opens on mouse-over, not on click, and hide it when the user mouses out:

```
map_1.save('map_1.html')
import re
import fileinput

with open("map_1.html") as inf:
   txt = inf.read()

#Find all the markers names given by folium
markers = re.findall(r'\bmarker_\w+', txt)
markers = list(set(markers))

for linenum,line in enumerate( fileinput.FileInput("map_1.html",inplace=1) ):
    pattern = markers[0] + ".bindPopup"
    pattern2 = markers[0] + ".on('mouseover', function (e) {this.openPopup();});"
    pattern3 = markers[0] + ".on('mouseout', function (e) {this.closePopup();});"

    if pattern in line:
       print(line.rstrip())
       print(pattern2)
       print(pattern3)
    else:
       print(line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is asking about **folium**, and I don't think so, but I think you can add some Javascript (with jquery it'd be super easy I suspect), to simulate a click event `onmouseover` or `mouseenter`

```
  var test = document.getElementById("test");

  test.addEventListener("mouseenter", handlerClickFunction);
```

Comment: Yes, I do not think folium can do it. Another solution is to directly use [leaflet](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32723/how-to-open-popup-on-mouseover-in-leaflet?rq=1)

Comment: Yeah very likely, sorry though, that's out of my knowledge :)