# Hovering Data for Choropleth maps In Folium

Tags: python, folium, choropleth

I am trying to make Choropleth maps in python using Folium tracking the amount of refugees into each state. My maps are running, but I want to create labels to show the state name and the amount of refugees that appear when I hover/click on each state. I am not sure if this is possible, but I would appreciate any help! Here is the code for my running map [Choropleth map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izVNl.png).

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import folium 

twentysa=pd.read_excel("State_abrv (9).xlsx")

url = (
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/examples/data"
)
state_geo = f"{url}/us-states.json"

h = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=state_geo,
    name="2013 Data",
    data=thirteensa,
    columns=["State", "Refugee Influx"],
    key_on="feature.id",
    fill_color="BuPu",
    fill_opacity=0.8,
    line_opacity=0.3,
    legend_name="2013 Refugee Influx",
).add_to(h)
h
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hover in popup in Folium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095716/hover-in-popup-in-folium)

Comment: I think this [sample page](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJsonPopupAndTooltip.ipynb) will be very useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use folium.GeoJSON to use the tooltip to enable the hover functionality. I've borrowed the below code from [here](https://vverde.github.io/blob/interactivechoropleth.html) and it worked for me. This is a starting point to allow the state to display upon hover, but this could be improved upon to show the refugee numbers as well.

```
# hover functionality

style_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#ffffff', 
                            'color':'#000000', 
                            'fillOpacity': 0.1, 
                            'weight': 0.1}
highlight_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#000000', 
                                'color':'#000000', 
                                'fillOpacity': 0.50, 
                                'weight': 0.1}
NIL = folium.features.GeoJson(
    state_geo,
    style_function=style_function, 
    control=False,
    highlight_function=highlight_function, 
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['name','id'],  # use fields from the json file
        aliases=['State: ','ID: '],
        style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;") 
    )
)
h.add_child(NIL)
h.keep_in_front(NIL)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(h)
```